# How to rotate rectangle in HTML canvas using Anime.js

Tags: javascript, html, animation, canvas

I have created a rectangle on HTML `canvas`. I want to have a 45 degree rotation animation on this rectangle using Anime.js. I have seen number of posts on rectangle rotation but can't figure out how to rotate it using Anime.js. Following is my `<body>` tag:

```
<body class="container">

<canvas></canvas>

<script src="anime.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script>

    document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function () {

        var canvas = document.querySelector('canvas');
        canvas.width = 1280;
        canvas.height = 720;

        var c = canvas.getContext('2d');

        //Create box
        function Box(size) {
            var box = {};
            box.size = size;
            box.x = 640 - (box.size/2);
            box.y = 250 - (box.size/2);
            box.translateX = 0;
            box.translateY = 0;
            box.degree = 0;
            box.color = "#ffffff";
            box.draw = function () {
                c.save();
                c.fillStyle = box.color;
                c.translate(box.translateX, box.translateY);
                c.rotate(box.degree * Math.PI/180);
                c.fillRect(box.x, box.y, box.size, box.size);
                c.restore();
            };
            return box;
        }
        var box = new Box(300);
        box.draw();

        anime.timeline().add({
            targets: box,
            x: -100,
            y: -125,
            translateX: 640,
            translateY: 250,
            degree: 45,
            duration: 1000
        })
    });


</script>
</body>
```

Can anyone please help?

Answer (score 0):

You mix up two different topics. Anime.js is good to animate dom elements. So in your case you can animate only complete canvas. Is not possible to animate rectangle inside. This is because animate.js is using DOM selectors and CSS technique. 
So to animate complete canvas you can assign id

```
canvas id="myCanvas"></canvas>
```

In java-script code change only target

```
        anime.timeline().add({
             targets: '#myCanvas',
```

Other way is to paint rotated rectangle by your own on canvas.

Comment: I understand. I guess Anime.js also uses javascript objects to animate. And I am trying to use that feature to animate the box inside canvas. Isn't it possible?? See this link https://codepen.io/juliangarnier/pen/xOgyjB

Comment: In this example is combination of HTML and SVG. So you can switch from Canvas to SVG solution.